# Difference between BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE and BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE_FRACTION?

Tags: boost

Can anyone describe the difference in behavior between `BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE` and `BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE_FRACTION`?  [The documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/testing-tools/reference.html) implies the that both macros treat their third parameter identically, which makes me suspect the documentation is wrong.

In particular, `BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE_FRACTION` gives me some odd looking results:

```
error in "...": difference between *expected{0} and *actual{-1.7763568394002506e-16} exceeds 9.9999999999999995e-07
```

Is there a gotcha because I expect a zero result?  I've not been successful at reading through the underlying macro declarations.  Please note `BOOST_CHECK_SMALL` isn't appropriate for my use case (comparing two vectors after a linear algebra operation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this discussion](http://www.nabble.com/Re:-Boost.Test-feature-request-p7281796.html), one (`BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE`) treats the third parameter as expressing a percent, while the other (`BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE_FRACTION`) treats it as expressing a fraction.  So, .01 in the first should be equivalent to .0001 in the second.

Not certain if that explains your problem -- do you get the same odd result with `BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE`?  I wouldn't be shocked if the 0 caused an issue -- but I don't have first hand experience with the macros.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

It does seem that the zero causes the issue, and that similar behavior occurs with one zero argument for both BOOST\_CHECK\_CLOSE and BOOST\_CHECK\_CLOSE\_FRACTION

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Zero is not "close" to any value. You can use BOOST_CHECK_SMALL instead.

Answer (score 2):

@Gennadiy: Zero **can** be close to any *small* value. :-) *Relative* differences grow arbitrarily large if the expected value is very close to zero.

Here is a workaround function I use to unit-test double values: if the expected value is very small or zero then I check the smallness of the observed value, otherwise I check closeness:

```
void dbl_check_close(
    double expected, double observed, 
    double small, double pct_tol
) {
    if (std::fabs(expected) < small) {
        BOOST_CHECK_SMALL(observed, small);
    } else {
        BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(expected, observed, pct_tol);
    }
}
```

Of course it would be great to have a `BOOST_CHECK_SMALL_OR_CLOSE` macro that does this automatically. Gennadiy could perhaps talk to the author of Boost.Test ;-)