# Boost unittest: BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE returns 1.#INF%

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I'm using the Boost unit test-framework to compare doubles with each other. The results are as expected, but BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE does not recognize them correctly I guess. The code is essentially as follows:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(FooBarTest)
{
    double foo = 2.2500000047015632e-006;
    double bar = 0.0;
    double tolerance = 90.0;
    BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(foo, bar, tolerance);
}
```

This fails with the following message:

```
error in [...]: difference{1.#INF%} between foo{2.2500000047015632e-006} and bar{0} exceeds 90%
```

I'm using Boost 1.55 with VC100 (Visual Studio 10 compiler). I'm compiling Win32 Release.

Is this a result I should expect? I would imagine that these values are close enough to each other and it should return success. Is Boost internally dividing by 0.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use BOOST_CHECK_SMALL to check closeness to zero.
For more background information, see: [Boost UTF documentation, article on floating-point comparison algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/testing-tools/floating_point_comparison.html).

Answer (score 1):

That's because `bar` is zero. BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE checks if the two values are 'close', that is, in your case, with 90% of each other. For that, you use division, and you can't divide by 0.

Or, as this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1218269/871910) so succinctly explains - zero is not close to anything.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I hadn't found anything usable when searching